# Selecting data from subdatasheet in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

In Access I have a table called School with a subdatasheet or inner-table, such as Teachers.

When clicking the + on Teachers I have a variety of information such as TeacherID, DateEmployed, TeacherScope, etc.

What I want to do is select, say, TeacherID and TeacherScope from within this subdatasheet. Of course if I do something like this...

```
SELECT Teachers.TeacherID FROM Teachers GROUP BY Teachers.TeacherID;
```

...it asks me to enter the parameter value of "Teachers.TeacherID".

I hope I'm making sense. This is just an example of what I'm trying to do and not the real table. I just want to be able to select data from within the subdatasheet and I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

Comment: What you have is a table and related table. Look at your relationship diagram and find out which table is related. It is also possible that the table under the + is set in the design of the main table. Look for a subdatasheet name in properties. You need a table name to build a query.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure what to call it so I was unable to really browse for help in a search engine. I'll keep trying, thanks. :)